# La « ducasse » : variantes régionales ?

Tags: régionalismes, synonymes, france, belgique

> [...] Il y avait une grande **ducasse** (fête foraine, ndlr) mes
>   copines passaient pour que je vienne, mais ma mère disait: "Ta place
>   est derrière le comptoir"», raconte-t-elle d'un ton sévère, imitant sa
>   voix.
>
> [ [*Marie-Lou, toujours derrière le bar à 100 ans*](http://www.lapresse.ca/vins/actualites/201712/07/01-5146278-marie-lou-toujours-derriere-le-bar-a-100-ans.php), ds. LaPresse, de l'AFP, propos de Madame Marie-Louise Wirth à Isbergues, aujourd'hui propriétaire et centenaire ! ]

La *ducasse* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ducasse), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ducasse/26925?q=ducasse#26791), nord de la France et sud de la Belgique nous dit-on), signifiant la *fête patronale de village* ou [*kermesse*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/kermesse), est une forme dialectale attestée en moyen français (1391) de la *dicasse* en ancien français (fin 12<sup>e</sup> qui est une réduction de la [*dédicace*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9dicace) (DHLF/Rey), la *consécration* de l'église du village, et par métonymie la fête commémorant cet évènement...

---

- Comprend-on *ducasse* partout en France et en Belgique ou ailleurs même si l'emploi était régional ?
- Existe-t-il d'autres variantes régionales ou emplois particuliers du genre ailleurs en France et dans la francophonie pour ce type de fête ([foraine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foraine), de village...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Belgique, le terme "ducasse" est effectivement couramment employé, et sera compris dans toute la Belgique francophone, mais n'est pas utilisé uniformément dans tout le pays.

Il est utilisé principalement dans l'Ouest de la Wallonie (grosso modo dans la province du Hainaut). Il y existe des ducasses "historiques" bien connues en Belgique qui sont des importantes fêtes folkloriques s'articulant autour d'une procession. Dans ce cas, il serait vraiment incongru (voire sacrilège !) d'utiliser un autre mot: les médias parleront de la ducasse de Mons ou d'Ath et n'utiliseront pas un autre terme.

"Ducasse" y est aussi utilisé (sans doute par extension) pour des fêtes qui n'ont pas (ou plus) pour événement central une procession: il s'agit alors de l'équivalent d'une fête de village, avec par exemple fête foraine, concerts, animations pour les enfants, brocante, braderie, chapiteau avec débit de boissons, etc. Notez donc qu'une ducasse n'est pas une simple fête foraine; il peut y avoir une fête foraine lors de la ducasse, mais elle constituera pas à elle seule la ducasse. Le village qui organise cette fête peut l'appeler  "ducasse de Trucmuche", mais il ne serait pas incongru d'y réferer simplement comme la "fête de village de Trucmuche" ou simplement "fête de Trucmuche".

Dans d'autres régions, par influence du néerlandais, on parle de "kermesse" pour l'équivalent d'une ducasse. Mais le terme "kermesse", au contraire du mot "ducasse", peut aussi désigner une simple fête foraine. Par exemple, à Bruxelles, il y a tous les ans une grande fête foraine dont le nom officiel est "foire du Midi", qu'on peut aussi qualifier de "kermesse".

Sur le sujet, et pour une étude linguistique très sérieuse sur le sujet: le blog "français de nos régions" y a consacré un [article](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/09/19/les-denominations-de-la-fete-de-village/) très complet.

Note: étant belge, je ne m'aventurerai pas à commenter sur l'utilisation du terme en France. A priori, vu la proximité culturelle, je pense que "ducasse" est utilisé de la même façon dans le Nord.

Answer (score 2):

Voici une carte représentant quelques noms régionaux des fêtes de village en France et alentours francophones. On voit bien la portée géographique de *ducasse* (principalement Picardie, Flandre française et Hainaut) qui ne sera probablement pas compris ailleurs, de même que *vogue*, *(fête) votive*, *assemblée*, *frairie*, *bénichon*, *abbaye*, *kirb*, *messti* et *kilbe*.

À l'inverse, *fest-Noz* est typiquement breton mais le terme est connu partout en France, de même que *feria* utilisé en Catalogne, Occitanie et au Pays-Basque, ainsi qu'à Nîmes et Arles. *Kermesse*, lui, est employé un peu partout en France.

[image]

Source:
[L’évolution des dénominations de la ‘fête de village’ (1906-2016)
19 SEPTEMBRE 2017 PAR MATHIEU AVANZI](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/09/19/les-denominations-de-la-fete-de-village/)

Answer (score 1):

Je viens du nord-pas-de-calais et c'est bien "ducasse" qu'on utilise pour dire "fête foraine". Je me souviens avoir dit le mot "ducasse" à des gens venant du sud de la France et le terme n'était pas compris. Il semble donc que ce terme soit bien d'usage uniquement dans la nord de la France et la Belgique.

Pour ce qui est de "kermesse" c'est le terme que beaucoup de monde utilise chez moi pour dire "fête de fin d'année" pour l'école primaire du village (avec les jeux, ventes de crêpes,... organisées dans la cour de l'école).

Answer (score 1):

En Bretagne, ce terme n'est pas utilisé .. à ma connaissance. Je doute que quelqu'un comprenne de quoi il s'agit si on lui dit "il y a une grande ducasse le week-end prochain .."

Comment: Vous connaissez ou employez _fest-Noz_ ? Merci !

Comment: Idem j'ai habité dans tout l'ouest, jamais entendu ce mot que je ne connaissais pas. Par contre oui, fest-noz est très parlant.

Comment: Oui, _fest-noz_ est utilisé en Bretagne, mais attention, il n'a pas le même sens. Il désigne une fête traditionnelle qui a lieu la nuit (d'où le_ noz_), avec des musiciens, où l'on vient pour danser ..